# How to divide unknown amount of li items responsively

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm working on my responsive portfolio site, and I'm stuck on something. When I have a portfolio item, I'd like to display thumbnails under a bigger image, which when clicked (onclick) change the big image. The problem is, I don't know how to divide them evenly across the div.. Also, the amount of li items will be different for other portfolio items.. Does anybody know a solution to this, preferrably in CSS? Thanks a lot in advance! - Jan

[image: Example of the problem]

The HTML code:

```
<article class="row">
  <div class="seven columns">
    <div id="mediadiv">
      <video controls autoplay><source src="mp4/ApocolyspeWow1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>

    <ul class="thumbnaillist">
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" onclick="changeMediaDiv('http://janvandijk.me/img/static/prof.jpg');"/></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/101x100" onclick="changeMediaDiv('mp4/ApocolyspeWow1080p.mp4');" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" onclick="changeMediaDiv('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg');" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" onclick="changeMediaDiv('R2lZH4RYTCY.youtube');" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" onclick="changeMediaDiv('');" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="five columns">
    <h3>Lalalalala</h3>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt, repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate maiores repudiandae nostrum reiciendis facere nemo ut temporibus asperiores ad iusto. Facere illo rem soluta consequatur.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: what about the LI height? (do you need to keep them square-alike?)

Comment: what if you'll have say 20 thumbnails?

Comment: I think there will never be more than 7-8 thumbnails, they will always be square, and I'd like them to stay on the same 'line'.. :)

Answer (score 3):

`display:table` for the UL and `table-cell` for the LI elements

```css
.seven{position:relative;width:56%;}
video{display:block;width:100%;}

.thumbnaillist{
  padding:0;
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.thumbnaillist li{
  display:table-cell;
}
.thumbnaillist li img{
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="seven columns">
    <div id="mediadiv">
      <video controls autoplay><source src="mp4/ApocolyspeWow1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>

    <ul class="thumbnaillist">
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/101x100/5fc"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/55c"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/c55"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f5c"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse! This comment is a bit late, but how do I add an margin to these cells while keeping the outer ones the same height? When I add an margin to all cells now, and remove set margin-left to 0 on the left one and margin-right to 0 on the right one the have different heights.. Thanks in advance!